# default case for if statement (if not specified)

Tags: python

I have a control statement as following:

```
        if x < 0 or x >= ht or y < 0 or y >= wdt: 
            im_warped[i][j] = 0
        else:
            im_warped[i][j] = im[x][y]
```

which gives the same result as following:

```
        if 0 < x < ht and 0 < y < wdt:
            im_warped[i][j] = im[x][y]
```

I am not specifying an else case for the second control statement, eventhough I am sure that such values (exceeding the bounds) do exist. So what exactly is happening here? Do they automatically get assigned to zero / null values (which I think is unlikely)

Comment: If there is no `else` and the `if` condition is not true, nothing will happen in that statement. Could you clarify what you are asking? Preferably with a [mcve]?

Comment: Can you show how `im_warped` is declared? I think these 0s are just its default values

Comment: your two `if` statements are not equivalent. In any case, there is no default. It is impossible to say what is going on without a [mcve].

Comment: The second `if` just negates the condition of the first; the only difference is that "out-of-bounds" indices aren't initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if` statements have blocks, not values. You seem to be confusing this with the [ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). For instance, in Tableau, if you write

```
 if condition then
       x
 else 
      y
 end
```

then when `condition` is true, this whole statement will be evaluated as having the value of `x`. If you write

```
z = if condition then x else y end
```

then whenever `condition` is true, the expression `if condition then x else y` will be evaluated as being `x`, and so `x` will be assigned to `z`.

In Python, however, if you write

```
if condition then:
      x
```

Python expects `x` to not be a *value*, but an *instruction*. In your first example, you had `im_warped[i][j]=0`. This is an instruction: it tells Python to assign `0` to `im_warped[i][j]`. If you were to write

```
   z = if condition:
          x 
       else:
          y
```

that will return an error in Python, because in Python if-then-else is not the ternary operator, it's a control statement. It does not return *any* values, conditional or default. Rather, it *runs code*. The "default", to the extent there is one, is to not run any code. When you wrote `if x < 0 or x >= ht or y < 0 or y >= wdt: im_warped[i][j] = 0`, it is not the `if-then-else` statement that is returning a value; you are putting a value of `0` *within* the code that it is running.

There is a ternary operator in Python, but its syntax is slightly different: it is `conditional_result if condition else default`. So your first example could be written as

```
   im_warped[i][j] = 0 if x < 0 or x >= ht or y < 0 or y >= wdt else im[x][y]
```

and if you were to write

```
        im_warped[i][j] = im[x][y] if 0 < x < ht and 0 < y < wdt
```

without an `else`, that would return an error.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have an else block, then nothing else will happen to the data. Your `im_warped` array will only have an entry modified in accordance with your if statement

The answer to your question, then, depends on what happens to that data before reaching this if statement. If it's a `numpy` array created with `np.zeros`, then all of its entries are 0 by default. If it's data that you're getting from somewhere else, those default values could be anything and depend on what the input data looks like.